# Unknown software exception error every time I turn on

Tags: windows-10, hp-pavilion, error-correction

recently, every time I start up my HP all-in-one running Windows 10, I get an error message that reads:

> **Hidden Window: HPSystemEventUtilityHost.exe - Application Error**
>
> The exception unknown software exception (0xe0434352) occurred in the
> application at location 0x00007FFDB98B4ED9.
>
> *OK*

I click 'OK' each time and suffer no adverse consequences.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Is there anything in the system event logs?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the software connected to HPSystemEventUtilityHost since its third-party and strictly speaking absolutely isn’t required for Windows to function

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the erroring software is HP System Event Utility. It is preinstalled on some HP machines and seems to be used to provide system hotkeys to change things such as brightness adjustment.

You can download an updated version at https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c06559359 which appears to be a reasonably up to date version released as a security update.